# New Update of elementary OS 5.1 Hera breaks Wifi Card

Tags: wifi, release-hera, lenovo

My laptop is Lenovo Ideapad C340 and i have installed elementary OS 5.1 Hera. The Wifi works out of the box.

However when i updated the suggested updates from the AppCenter two days back wifi card disappeared.

When i reinstall the elementary OS 5.1 Hera wifi works and if i update wifi stops.

I tried several methods described to correct the problem none seems to work.

my wifi card details are

```
    description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlp0s20f3
   version: 00
   serial: 08:71:90:b9:86:56
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-28-generic firmware=48.13675109.0 ip=192.168.1.190 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:b4318000-b431bfff
```

So i would like your help in sorting this problem. I noticed that kernel is 5.3.0-28-generic and  after the update is it 5.4 something .... it is the kernel update that breaks it ?

How to fix this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"I tried several methods described to correct the problem none seems to work. "

Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Asus ZenBook (just shipped) with an Intel 9000 series wireless adapter built in, and I had the same problem. I solved it by manually installing the backport of iwlwifi using the advice of "jeremy31" here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi

Note that the first recommended install didn't solve my problem; it was the second step (getting the newer version from Canonical) that actually solved my problem.